# Python daemon library import error

Tags: python, daemon

I get error with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, time, daemon

class MyDaemon(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = MyDaemon('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print("Unknown command")
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(2)
```

It yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dtest2.py", line 5, in <module>
    class MyDaemon(Daemon):
NameError: name 'Daemon' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? I have installed daemon with 'sudo pip install daemon'.

UPDATE: following the advice from @DeepSpace I have changed the code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, time, daemon

class MyDaemon(daemon.Daemon):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = MyDaemon('/tmp/daemon-example.pid')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print("Unknown command")
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(2)
```

...and it yields a different error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dtest.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sys, time, daemon
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/daemon.py", line 70
    os.umask(022)   # Don't allow others to write
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`import sys, time, daemon` does not tell the interpreter where does the `Daemon` class come from.

Either change `class MyDaemon(Daemon)` to `class MyDaemon(daemon.Daemon)`,

**or** change

`import sys, time, daemon`

to

```
import sys
import time
from daemon import Daemon
```

According to PEP8 [each `import` should be on its own line anyway](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: None of them made any difference. I've tried changing the import statements according to your advice and change class MyDaemon(Daemon) to class MyDaemon(daemon.Daemon). I get 'ImportError: No module named daemon'. What do I do wrong???

Comment: @alkopop79 You should have changed either of them, *not* both. Please update your question to include your most recent code and the most recent error you are getting. **Also** make sure the name of your script is not  daemon.py by any chance.